# htaccess rewrite all to index.html

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to write the `.htaccess` file so that whatever the user requests, he will have the page `index.html`

I've written this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* index.html [NC]
```

I understand that this will cause: whatever the incoming request URL is, i.e, `www.domain.com/***` (whatever comes after the slash), the result will be the page `www.domain.com/index.html`

However, I'm getting a Server error. What am I missing?

NOTE: I don't want it to be permanent redirect, I'm just trying to "hide" the content of my site for a couple of hours with that `index.html` page (which says that the site is under maintenance).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to remove `Options +FollowSymlinks` , some servers won't allow you to overwrite a php.ini setting.

Comment: I don't want it to be permanent redirect, I just want to "hide" everything for a couple of hours.

Comment: Ok, i've removed the `R=301` rule ;)

Comment: Are you sure your server supports custom .htaccess ? Have you tried removing `Options +FollowSymlinks` ?

Answer (score 14):

If you want to redirect everything to **temporary** maintenance page, you can do :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance.html$
RewriteRule .* /maintenance.html [L,R=302]
```

the R=302 flag is used to generate a temporary redirect

Comment: this generates an infinite loop and server does not respond!