# vue-router does not redirect

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Despite of multiple posts on the subject I can't find what is going wrong. I been followed this [example](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/examples/redirect/app.js).

Here is my `VueRouter` instance.

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      component: require("./components/producer-table.vue").default
    },
    {
      path: "/producer/:producerId",
      component: require("./components/variable-table.vue").default,
      props: true
    },
    { path: "*", redirect: "/" }
  ]
});
```

If I route to a wrong url programmatically (`this.$router.push({path: "/wrong});`) I am redirected to http://localhost/.

Everything seems to work fine except that when I set a wrong address in Chrome url bar I get the following message:

> Cannot GET /wrong

I would expect http://localhost/wrong to be redirected to http://localhost/. I'm quite new using vue router and I'm must miss something. Any ideas?

Comment: This is explained in the [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your webserver doesn't know `GET /wrong` should be redirected to the `index.html` file; from there on, `vue-router` can take over.

Some examples on how to redirect different web servers;

**Apache:** [htaccess rewrite all to index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495897/htaccess-rewrite-all-to-index-html)

**nginx:** [Rewrite all requests to index.php with nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924896/rewrite-all-requests-to-index-php-with-nginx)

**webpack-dev-server:**

```
/// in your webpack.config
devServer: {
  historyApiFallback: {
    index: '/'
  }
}
```